# A Game of Number Cards

Tags: probability, card-games

In a cards game, there are ten cards, $1$ to $10$. Two players, seated facing each other, randomly choose $5$ cards each. They arrange their cards in ascending order of the number on the cards as shown below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sRqU.png

The difference between the corresponding cards is calculated such that the lower value is subtracted from the higher value.

In a random game, what is the probability that the sum of the differences is $24$?

The answer to this is **$0$**.

[I observed that in such an experiment, we obtain the sum of such differences as **$25$** *always*].

How do I solve it?

**Edit**: To avoid any confusion, I want to make it clear that the image only implies that one player arranged his cards in ascending order from *left to right* and the other from *right to left* as observed in top view of the table from either player's end.

Comment: The image does not show what is going on well at all.  The cards are too small to see the numbers.  If one of the players gets all the odds and the other gets all the evens wouldn't the result be $5$?  What have you tried?

Comment: Actually no numbers are written on the cards in the image. It is given just to show that one player has arranged his cards in the ascending order from *left to right* and the other player has arranged from *right to left*

Comment: Which seems to indicate that the largest two cards are compared, then the two next largest, and so on.  It won't always be $25$

Comment: Yes it implies that. Please provide an example where it isn't 25

Comment: "Please provide an example where it isn't 25"  Well if one player has $1,3,5,7,9$ and the other $2,4,6,8,10$ it'd by $4$.  The biggest different between the lowest is if one player has the lowest possible ($1$) and the other has the highest possible low.  As the other player must have four cards higher than the lowest, the highest low is $6$.  In this case the greatest difference is $5$.

Comment: @fleablood See the last sentence of the question. In your example, we get $(10-1)+(8-3)+(6-5)+(7-4)+(9-2) = 25$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov  "one player has arranged his cards in the ascending order from left to right and the other player has arranged from right to left"  So player one lays them from west to east as 1,3,5,7,9 and player two lays them east to west as 2,4,6,7,8.  If you compare them from west to east the are $(1,2)(3,4)(5,6),(7,8)(9,10)$ or from eat to west as $(9,10)(7,8),(5,6),(3,4),(12)$ Either way, the sum is $1$.

Comment: @fleablood Okay, it's true that "from right to left" is still ambiguous; do we mean the observer's right and left, or each individual's right and left? But given that it's meant to clarify a photo on which you *can*, just barely, make out the arrows of which way ascending order goes, and given that the other interpretation *does* consistently yield $25$, I think we can figure out from context which it should be.

Comment: @MishaLavrov  Ah, you are correct.   It's basically lowest to highest compared.  That can be proven to be always 25 I believe.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: prove that no matter how you arrange the cards, the cards $1,2,3,4,5$ are opposite some higher-value card, while the cards $6,7,8,9,10$ are opposite some lower-value card. (Think about it one card at a time: what would it take for $5$ to end up opposite one of $1,2,3,4$, for example?)

If you prove this, then it follows that taking the sum of positive differences is equivalent to the calculation $$10+9+8+7+6-5-4-3-2-1,$$ just done in a different order, so it is guaranteed to yield $25$.

Comment: Yes now I'm able to understand what's going on. So there are 10!/(2!5!5!) cases, but in each case, the final arrangement of cards in both rows is such that card facing each of 6,7,8,9,10 is always less than 6

Comment: Right... A persons lowest card (which must be 5 or lower) must go against someones highest (which must be 6 or higher). Second lowest goes to second higest. Second lowest can only be as high as $6$ if the other player has four of the five lowest in which case the second highest  in one of those lower cards.  And we can generalize the $i_{\le 5}$ can only be $6$ or higher if the other player had $5-i$ of the lowest cards and if so the $i$th highest must be one of these lower ones.  As every difference is one of the high against low the sum of difference is the sums of highs against lows. NICE!